# Possible values of $N$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the number of values of $N$ such that the below expression is an integer:
 $(n+1)^2\over n+7$ is an integer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1=(n+7)(n-5)+36$

So, $\frac{(n+1)^2}{n+7}=n-5+\frac{36}{n+7}$

Assuming $n$ to be an integer, $(n+7)\mid36 \iff (n+7)\mid(n+1)^2$

So, $n+7$ can be any divisor  of $36,$ namely $\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\pm4,\pm6,\pm9,\pm12,\pm18,\pm36$

If we constrain $n$ to be non-negative i.e., if $n+7\ge 7,$ then $n+7$ can be  $9,12,18,36$

Comment: I don't think this is right; for example $n=65$ satisfies your criterion, but not the equation required by the asker.

Comment: @RossMillikan, thanks Ross, you took my burden.

Comment: @RossMillikan: He edited it: he had the condition "$(n+7)\ |\ 36m$ for integer $m$" as a condition.

Comment: @Fixee, are you ok with the current version? Also, I don't know where the version you are talking about is lost.